# How to have some of the frames start collapsed

Tags: javascript, iframe

I just need some advice. I'm trying to show some frames on my page, and have them collapsable. This works fine right now, but what I'm looking to do is have some of the frames start collapsed and then use a link to make them visible.

I'm not a javascript expert, but hopefully someone out there can give me a hint or suggest something in the right direction. Here's the code I'm testing:

```
<!--  Begin Javascript for expanding menus -->`
<script>`
function ShowHide(tab) {
  var t = document.getElementById(tab);
  if (t.style.display == '') {
        t.style.display = 'none';
        t.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  else {
        t.style.display = '';
        t.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

function ShowAll() {
  var t = document.getElementById('info');
  for (var i = 0; i < t.rows.length; i++) {
        if (t.rows[i].id != "control") {
              t.rows[i].style.display = '';
              t.rows[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
  }
}

function CollapseAll() {
  var t = document.getElementById('info');
  for (var i = 0; i < t.rows.length; i++) {
        if (t.rows[i].id != "control") {
              t.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
              t.rows[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- End Java script to expand menus -->

</head>
<body>

<!------- Start top of page ---------->
<!------- Menu on left of page to expand/collapse menus ---------->
<a href="javascript:ShowAll()">Expand all menus</a>&nbsp;
<br>
<a href="javascript:CollapseAll()">Collapse all menus</a></br>
<center>
<!------- End menu on left of page to expand/collapse menus ---------->

<table id="info"> <!-- Begin table for java menus -->

<!------- Begin Display Yahoo ---------->
<tr id="control">
<td bgcolor="#007700" width="100%" id="block1" 
class="sectionOpen"   onClick="ShowHide('StableTab')">
<center><font   color="#FFFFFF">Yahoo</center></td>
</tr>
<tr id="StableTab">
<td width="100%">
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com" name="stableFrame" width="780" height="550">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<!------- End Display Yahoo ---------->


<!------- Begin Display of Google ---------->
<tr id="control">
<td width="100%" id="block2" class="sectionOpen" onClick="ShowHide ('GTab')">
<center>Google info</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="GTab">
<td width="100%">
<iframe src="http://google.com" name="gInfoFrame" width="650" height="120">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<!------- End Display of Google ---------->
</table> <!-- End table for java menus -->
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To control the Shown/Hidden state through classes, you can do the following.

TLDR: [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/creighcl/wuufrfwo/)

You'll need to add a little CSS:

```
<style>
.iFrameRow {
  display: '';
}
.iFrameRow.collapsed {
  display: none;
}
</style>
```

Now, apply the "iFrameRow" to both of the rows that are collapsible, namely StableTab and GTab. So whenever any iFrameRows also have the class of "collapsed", they'll be hidden. In this way, you can default one to start off hidden by adding the collapsed class.

Now our javascript just needs to be able to add and remove that collapsed class to do the actual toggling:

```
function ToggleById(id){
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  ShowHide(element);
}

function ShowHide(tab, forceShow){
  //if forceShow is not defined, we'll just toggle
  if (forceShow === undefined){ 
    forceShow = tab.classList.contains('collapsed');
  }
  if (forceShow){
    tab.classList.remove('collapsed');
  } else {
    tab.classList.add('collapsed');
  }
}

function ShowAll() {
  var allMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.iFrameRow');
  for(var i=0;i<allMenus.length;i++){
    ShowHide(allMenus[i],true); //forceShow set to true
  }
}

function CollapseAll() {
  var allMenus = document.querySelectorAll('.iFrameRow');
  for(var i=0;i<allMenus.length;i++){
    ShowHide(allMenus[i],false); //forceShow set to false
  }
}
```

The only other modification besides adding the 'iFrameRow' class to the collapsible elements that we need to do is have these 'sectionOpen' elements now point to our new ToggleById method and we're done!

note: i did add the collapsed class to StableTab so currently Yahoo starts off as hidden

```
<!------- Start top of page ---------->
<!------- Menu on left of page to expand/collapse menus ---------->
<a href="javascript:ShowAll()">Expand all menus</a>&nbsp;
<br>
<a href="javascript:CollapseAll()">Collapse all menus</a></br>
<center>
<table id="info"> <!-- Begin table for java menus -->

<!------- Begin Display Yahoo ---------->
<tr id="control">
<td bgcolor="#007700" width="100%" id="block1" 
class="sectionOpen"   onClick="ToggleById('StableTab')">
<center><font   color="#FFFFFF">Yahoo</center></td>
</tr>
<tr id="StableTab" class="iFrameRow collapsed"> 
<td width="100%">
<iframe src="http://yahoo.com" name="stableFrame" width="780" height="550">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<!------- End Display Yahoo ---------->


<!------- Begin Display of Google ---------->
<tr id="control">
<td width="100%" id="block2" class="sectionOpen" onClick="ToggleById('GTab')">
<center>Google info</center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr id="GTab" class="iFrameRow">
<td width="100%">
<iframe src="http://google.com" name="gInfoFrame" width="650" height="120">
</iframe>
</td>
</tr>
<!------- End Display of Google ---------->
</table> <!-- End table for java menus -->
</center>
```